# How to create a numeric input component in Vue with limits that doesn't allow to type outside limits

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to create a numeric input component in Vue with min and max values that doesn't allow to type outside outside limits without success:

```html
<template id="custom-input">
  <div>
    <input :value="value" type="number" @input="onInput">
  </div>
</template>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <span>Value: {{ value }}</span>
    <custom-input v-model="value" :max-value="50"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
Vue.component('custom-input', {
  template: '#custom-input',
  props: {
    value: Number,
    maxValue: Number
  },
  methods: {
    onInput(event) {
      const newValue = parseInt(event.target.value)
      const clampedValue = Math.min(newValue, this.maxValue)
      this.$emit('input', clampedValue)
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    value: 5
  }
})
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/8dzhy5bk/6/

In the previous example, the max value is set in 50. If I type 60 it's converted automatically to 50 inside the input, but if I type a third digit it allow to continue typing. The value passed to the parent is clamped, but I also need to limit the input so no more digits can be entered.

Comment: Have you tried assigning `min` & `max` in your input tag?

Comment: Yes, but doesn't work

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number) all browsers (except possibly Edge?) fully support number input elements, including `min` and `max` attributes. Why do you say they don't work

Comment: @StephenThomas, because I tried that before and didn't work. Try this updated fiddle with max="50" in the input tag and type 500 https://jsfiddle.net/8dzhy5bk/9/

Comment: @StephenThomas according to MDN: "You can still manually enter a number outside these bounds, but it will be considered invalid." That's the behavior I wanted to change, disallow the user to enter a value outside the bounds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the value of input is great than 10, it will always emit 10 to parent component, but the value **keeps same** (always=10) so it **will not trigger reactvity**.

**One solution**, always emit actual value (=`parseInt(event.target.value)`) first, then emit the max value (=`Math.min(newValue, this.maxValue)`) in `vm.$nextTick()`

**Another solution** is use `this.$forceUpdate()`.

Below is **the demo** for `$nextTick`.

```js
Vue.component('custom-input', {
  template: '#custom-input',
  props: {
    value: Number,
    maxValue: Number
  },
  methods: {
    onInput(event) {
      const newValue = parseInt(event.target.value)
      const clampedValue = Math.min(newValue, this.maxValue)
      this.$emit('input', newValue)
      this.$nextTick(()=>{
       this.$emit('input', clampedValue)
      })
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    value: 5
  },
  methods: {
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>

<template id="custom-input">
  <div>
    <input 
      :value="value" 
      type="number" 
      @input="onInput" 
     >
  </div>
</template>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <span>Value: {{ value }}</span>
    <custom-input v-model="value" :max-value="10"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Below is **the demo** for `vm.$forceUpdate`.

```js
Vue.component('custom-input', {
  template: '#custom-input',
  props: {
    value: Number,
    maxValue: Number
  },
  methods: {
    onInput(event) {
      const newValue = parseInt(event.target.value)
      const clampedValue = Math.min(newValue, this.maxValue)
      this.$emit('input', clampedValue)
      this.$forceUpdate()
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    value: 5
  },
  methods: {
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>

<template id="custom-input">
  <div>
    <input 
      :value="value" 
      type="number" 
      @input="onInput" 
     >
  </div>
</template>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <span>Value: {{ value }}</span>
    <custom-input v-model="value" :max-value="10"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$forceUpdate()` worked. This is the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8dzhy5bk/7/. I noted that I posted a previous fiddle in my original question with some errors.

Comment: @Camilo, `vm.$nextTick()` also works, check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8dzhy5bk/8/)

Comment: Your edit with :max="maxValue" doesn't work. Try typing 100. The expected result is 10 in the input field, not 100. Your previous answer worked well.